# Signing key for an android app made in Godot

Tags: android, key, godot

I just made an easy game using Godot engine and I would like to upload the game on google play. I'm having big trouble with the "signing key". I'm a total noobie and I have never uploaded a game anywhere. I tried to follow some tutorials and I ended up creating a keystore in Android studio. Then I chose the file in Godot export settings under keystore > release.
Now I'm trying to upload the app but I'm getting this error:

ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_MANIFEST: Missing META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Any ideas?

Comment: http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/getting_started/workflow/export/exporting_for_android.html

Comment: tutorial to sign : https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Creating-a-Release-APK

Answer (score 0):

I would watch this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPI8JsKF2j4) or just follor my instructions below.
These are the paths you need after you downloaded JDK 1.8 [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and Android-Studio.

```
Path to the adb:
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\

Path to the jdk for jarsigner:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin

Path to the debug.keystore:
%HOMEPATH%/.android/debug.keystore
```

Now you have to copy the paths in the belonging textfield in the "Editor Settings" under Export/Android. That should look like this:

[Image: Editor Settings/Export/Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtJwV.png)

The only thing you have to do then is to export your game under "Project" by clicking on "Add..." and then on Android. Now you should be able to name the package to something like com.name (I think that's required).

I hope that the answer doesn't come too late and that it helps.